# Can we justify the notion of earthly defined success based on Quran?

Tags: quran, tafseer, islamic-philosophy

In Quran there are descriptions of good people. They are patient. They pray and give alms. They are abstinent, etc.

But these qualities, only make your soul a better soul. They don't make you a doctor, or an engineer, or a mathematician.

They don't make you a person capable of living a worldly life with honor and respect too.

Living in modern world needs one to constantly push his knowledge boundaries further and further. Otherwise, you only become something equivalent of the old peasants. And by this, you lose the power as an individual and also as a society to serve ALLAH (SWT), because you have no power whatsoever.

The great example is that the muslim society in average is highly behind technological and scientific levels of the modern world. A high percentage of scientists and theoreticians come from Atheists or Jews.

Now, I had a discussion with a family member about her laziness. She said, "I just want to live a normal life, and die. I will do what ALLAH (SWT) has askes me to do in Quran, and nothing more."

I felt that, this is not in accordance with teachings of ALLAH (SWT), but I could not bring forward reasons from Quran.

I have this sense that a muslim doctor, should become more expert as time passes. A muslim athlete should strive more to become a champion. A muslim individual should always seek progress. But now I'm not sure if this is true or not. If this is only a sense that I have, or is it also the command of ALLAH (SWT).

In other words, now I think a person can easily think of Islam as a disgusting faith with no emphasis on earthly success and 100% emphasis only on success in the afterlife. Thus, you as a muslim should be a loser in this world based on what it preaches.

Can you help me in this matter?

Comment: Islam is against lazy ess anyone claiming else has a wrong understanding of Islam.

Comment: Do we have Quranic proof?

Comment: The verb عمل (to work) and its corresponding noun العمل is quoted in the qur'an as it seems to me more than 100 times. The qur'an actually explicitly quotes four kinds of professions and professionals namely agriculture, crafting, trading and fishing... What else do you want?